# configuration.module has an unknown property 'use'

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

I'm trying to build a React application without using creat-react-app.

Here is my package.config.js:

```
//configurations for babel loader
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ],
        use: [
            {
                loader: "style-loader"
            },
            {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                    modules: true,
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
                    sourceMap: true,
                    minimize: true
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [htmlPlugin]
};
```

After I ran `npm start`, the error message showing on my console is:
`✖ ｢wds｣: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.`